# Java method Overloading with REST - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST service that has a POST endpoint. This POST endpoint needs to receive an object (`TravelRequisitionFormDTO`) as part of its body:

```
@POST
@Path("/request")
@ApiOperation(value="Request a trip. Submit the trip request.")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getSubmitTrip(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, @ApiParam(required = true) TravelRequisitionFormDTO travelRequisitionFormDTO, @Context HttpServletRequest request)  {
            ...
    }
```

So when I call the endpoint, I get the following error:

```
<p><b>message</b> <u>org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property
        &quot;contactMethods&quot;: utility.dataobjects.ContactObject#setContactMethods(1 params) vs
        utility.dataobjects.ContactObject#setContactMethods(1 params)</u></p>
<p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
        (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property
        &quot;contactMethods&quot;: utility.dataobjects.ContactObject#setContactMethods(1 params) vs
        utility.dataobjects.ContactObject#setContactMethods(1 params)).</u></p>
```

The reason for the error is because the `TravelRequisitionFormDTO` has a member variable (called `ContactObject`) that has two methods that are overloaded. So when it tries to convert the JSON body to JAVA, I guess it does not know which overloaded method to use. I think it sees it as ambiguous.

```
public void setContactMethods(ArrayList list)
```

and

```
public void setContactMethods(String[] list)
```

I don't want to change `ContactObject` if possible, because it is used in a number of other places.

**Question**

Is there any way I can resolve this? i.e. so that the JSON body can be converted successfuly into the Java object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep single property accepting List. and your Contractobject can consume both Array & List.

Comment: Hi @Dnyaneshwar, thank you for your answer.  I don't really understand, because there will still be 2 overloaded methods. Or am I missing something?  Can you perhaps give an example?

Comment: Hi @Richard so, your DTO class which is accumulating this request body, will search for appropriate setters, in your case you are having two methods one for accepting arraylist and other one for accepting array. since your client will always sending data in array form so, you you can still use single method of arraylist or array. you do not need two different methods. the clients array data can also be store in your setting arraylist method.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate one setter with Jackson @JsonSetter annotation:

```
@JsonSetter
public void setContactMethods(ArrayList list)
```

Make sure that you use right package. In your case it would be [org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonSetter.html) like you can see in the error message. It might happen that you have also [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) in the classpath so you have to be careful not to mix it.

Alternatively you can use @JsonProperty instead.

Comment: This did not work, I am not sure why. Maybe because I am using a very old version of Java (1.7).

Comment: Did you use the annotation from right package i.e. "org.codehaus.jackson.annotate"? The same annotation is defined also in another version of Jackson in different package: "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation", so you have to make sure you are using correct one. In your case it will be the first one as far as I see from stack trace.